# Targeting first element after CSS ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please see this codepen: http://codepen.io/muji/pen/XpEYzO

I need to target the first element **after** it has been sorted by a css "order" property and give it another CSS property.

Is there some jQuery or something I can use to find the first element after sorting, and then addClass, or something? Many thanks for any help

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.featured {
  order: 1;
}
.normal {
  order: 2;
}
.wrap div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

/*this is the part I need help with, as it should only apply to the first element AFTER applying the "order" attribute*/
.wrap div:first-of-type {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h3>wp_query 1 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>

<h3>wp_query 2 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So in the wp_query 1 output, you want the first "A featured item" to be the one that's red and 100% wide rather than the first Normal one?

Comment: Do you need a **general** solution related to `order`, or a specific solution related to the markup and styling above?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, as the `:nth-of-type` and other CSS position-based selectors (as well as JS) work on the position of the element in the DOM. The `order` rule doesn't affect the DOM - as can be seen if you check it using the inspector. It's a similar issue to that of pseudo selectors adding content. I'd suggest you change the logic to do the ordering in JS. While not ideal it will fix the issue, and also mean the code works better cross browser, as `order` is not yet well supported, esp. in IE see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Doing this with CSS is hard, not to mention `order` is not available in older browsers. Can you control the order of the elements as the html is generated?

Comment: T.J. Crowder: A specific one would probably be best for me, but for other people turning up here via google a general solution would probably be better.

Comment: Re @RobForrest's point:  Or, since you mention jQuery, change their order dynamically?

Comment: Rob Forrest: no, I can't control the order.  Is there a way to use jQuery to specifically target the first element after ordering and add a class to it, or something like that?

Comment: How would I change the order dynamically, TJ?

Comment: @plumbinator: *That's* easy, if you're interested in doing that.

Comment: @TJ, I'm very interested in any possible solution, hacky or otherwise, that will allow me to style the first element in a wp_query output after it has been reordered with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the position top suggested by @Nenad Vracar would be to actually filter the elements with the smallest `order` in each group and highlight the first one (*in terms of dom order*)

```js
$('.wrap').each(function() {
  var items = $(this).children(),
    minOrder = Infinity,
    details = items.map(function(i, el) {
      var order = +$(el).css('order');
      if (minOrder > order) minOrder = order;
      return {
        element: el,
        order: order
      };
    }).get(),
    firstElement = details.filter(function(item) {
      return item.order == minOrder;
    })[0];
  
  $(firstElement.element)
    .addClass('highlight')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('highlight');
  
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.featured {
  order: 1;
}
.normal {
  order: 2;
}
.wrap div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
/*this is the part I need help with, as it should only apply to the first element AFTER applying the "order" attribute*/

.wrap .highlight {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>wp_query 1 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>

<h3>wp_query 2 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>
```

---

If you were to alter the order based on media queries you should apply this code on resize.

Comment: This is great, thank you.  I went with this solution in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort inner divs by `position().top` and apply style on first one.

```js
$('.wrap').each(function() {
  var sort = $(this).find('div').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).position().top - $(b).position().top
  })
  $(sort[0]).addClass('first')
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.featured {
  order: 1;
}
.normal {
  order: 2;
}
.wrap div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
div.first {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>wp_query 1 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>

<h3>wp_query 2 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, if the relevant CSS is needed for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any [CSS selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) for "first in order" or the like (that *would* be handy, as `order` becomes more widely-adopted), so it probably will need to be a script-based solution (sadly).

You'd indicated that a solution involving *reordering* the elements might work for you. If so, that's dead easy. :-) See comments:

```js
// A worker function to tell us the priority of an element (low number = high priority)
function getPriority($el) {
  return $el.hasClass("featured") ? 0 : $el.hasClass("normal") ? 1 : 2;
}
// For each .wrap container...
$(".wrap").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  // Get an array of its child elements
  var a = $this.children().get();
  
  // Sort it, putting featured first, then normal, then any others
  a.sort(function(a, b) {
    return getPriority($(a)) - getPriority($(b));
  });
  
  // Append them to the parent, which moves them
  $this.append(a);
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

/* Just make the first div the highlighted one */
.wrap div:first-of-type {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h3>wp_query 1 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="featured">A featured item</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>

<h3>wp_query 2 output:</h3>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```